# T-SQL Optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

If the answer is 'No', I'm OK with that...

I'm looking to see if this can be optimized any...it's part of a much larger stored proc. `CGCode` is varchar(50), `Year` and `Month` are `smallint`, `FEIN` is `char(9)`

```
select max(id)
from Table
where 1=1
    and cgcode = 123
    and datefromparts(cast(year as char(4)),cast(month as char(2)),'01') < getdate()
    and totalcount > 0 
group by cgcode, year, month, fein
```

Logical reads from actual execution plan: 1,566,473

Source table raw data 32 million+ records

Estimated rows: 640K, actual 55K, before the Group By kicks in

Implicit conversion warnings on `Year/Month/CGCode` (comes in as `bigint`)

Execution time roughly 7.5 seconds, doing a Non-Clustered Index Seek:

[image]

End result set is 114 rows (for this `CGCode` we test with...others vary)

Performance is roughly the same in Prod on significantly better hardware than the Dev box.   This is only going to get worse over time, as its pulling everything older than the current month, to populate a history chart in a UI.

What other info can I provide?

[Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy8V_g1m-)

The index being used currently:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [COIX_Table_TotalCount] ON [dbo].[Table]
(
    [TotalCount] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ID],
    [CGCode],
    [Year],
    [Month],
    [FEIN]) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
        ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

`CGCode` limits the data most...281 values.  `year` is only 3-4 years worth of data, `month` only 12 options there of course.  `TotalCount` is a `bigint`, 17K distinct values across 32 million records.  No idea what the purpose of the `TotalCount` column is.

Comment: Well that explains the big I/O amounts, indexing CGCode should help a lot, and probably it should be the first field. If dates are (mostly) in the past, focusing on it probably doesn't change much.

Comment: Regarding: *"as its pulling everything older than the current month"*. No, the query is actually pulling everything in the past plus the whole current month. Unless you run it at the 1st day of the month, at exactly `'00:00:00.000'`.

Comment: You are correct...I misread that part of the code.   Developer has some 'splaining to do on that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I would rewrite this condition. As it is, it can't use any index effectively.:

```
datefromparts(cast(year as char(4)),cast(month as char(2)),'01') < getdate()
```

Rewrite it so there is no functions or calculations applied to the columns:

```
 ( year < year(getdate()) 
or year = year(getdate()) and month <= month(getdate())
 )
```

The rewrite would allow an index on `(cgcode, year, month)` to be used - or even better a `(cgcode, year, month, fein)` one, considering the `GROUP BY` parts.

Next, if `totalcount` is always part of the `WHERE` clause or thee specific `totalcount > 0` condition is always used, you might squeeze even more efficiency by adding it to the `INCLUDE` part or with a more targeted, filtered index:

```
-- option A
index (cgcode, year, month, fein, id) 
      include (totalcount)

-- option B
index (cgcode, year, month, fein, id)
      where (totalcount > 0)
```

Comment: @JacobH lets discuss further in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60484/t-sql-optimization)

Comment: Thanks...getting an index scan instead of seek, but I'll sort that out.  This gave me enough to work through it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will remove cgcode from Group By since I know what is cgcode and it is not range.So removing cgcode (varchar(60)) will give tremendous push.

So if I am correct my index will change too.

Use Variable in place of getdate()

```
declare @CurDate date=getdate()
declare @yr int=year(@CurDate ) 
declare @month tinyint=month(@CurDate )
declare @cg varchar(60)='123'

select @cg cgcode,max(id)
from Table
where  cgcode = @cg
    ( year < @yr  
or [year] = @yr and [month] <= @month
 )
    and totalcount > 0 
group by year, month, fein
```

Also technically why `totalcount will be covering index` in option A.I don't understand,by that logic it should within index group or `option B` is correct .

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)

The clientid is being passed in as INT...causing an implicit conversion to varchar for the CGCode field.

```
select max(id)
from Table
where 1=1
    and cgcode = CAST(123 as varchar(50))  ---this fixed it
    and datefromparts(cast(year as char(4)),cast(month as char(2)),'01') < getdate()
    and totalcount > 0 
group by cgcode, year, month, fein
```

From 7-30 seconds to 100ms.  I'll take that.